# Placing subplot at lat/long co-ordinates in cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to place a matplotlib axes at specific coordinates on a cartopy plot, but don't know how to set the location correctly. The code should:

- Plot an orthographic projection of Germany
- Add text 'Berlin' at the location of Berlin
- Add a histogram at the location of Berlin

The code I have is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

extent = [6, 15, 47, 55]          # Extent of Germany in Lat/Long

lat, lon = 52.520007, 13.404954   # Location of Berlin

# Plot our coastline and set the extent
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=10.5, \
         central_latitude=51.0, \
         globe=None))
ax.coastlines('10m')
ax.set_extent(extent)

# Add text at the location of Berlin
plt.text(lon, lat, 'Berlin', \
         verticalalignment='center', \
         horizontalalignment='right', \
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Add subplot
sub_ax = plt.axes([(lon-extent[0])/(extent[1] - extent[0]), \
                   (lat-extent[2])/(extent[3] - extent[2]), \
                   .1, .1], \
                   axisbg='none')

plt.hist(np.random.randn(100), 10, normed=1)
```

[image: Code output]

As you can see, the histogram is not located at Berlin, because (I presume) it's relative to the bounding box of the figure and not the axes. I've tried adding `transform=ax.transAxes` as you would with `plt.text`, but this gives an `unhashable type` error on `BboxTransformTo`.

I should add that I know my location calculation doesn't work in general because I'm not using a Euclidean geometry, but for my purposes it's close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should get the required locations relative to the edge of the figure:

```
ax_lon = (lon-extent[0])/(extent[1] - extent[0])
ax_lat = (lat-extent[2])/(extent[3] - extent[2])
fig_lon = (ax.bbox.x0 + ax_lon * ax.bbox.width) / fig.bbox.width
fig_lat = (ax.bbox.y0 + ax_lat * ax.bbox.height) / fig.bbox.height
```

But if the figure is resized these values become wrong. The only way I can think of to keep it in the right location when resizing is to use an event callback to update the location.

Comment: Belated thanks! I was still struggling to get this to work (though getting the bbox of the fig is very useful), and I realised that my using a jupyter notebook was messing things up a bit. The notebook was resizing the figure (so `figsize=(8,8)` actually meant "`8` high, but only as wide as you need to be".


The upshot of this is that I never considered resizing at all; when I tried it in IPython is worked as you described, but only until resized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
#import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

height = 18.
width = 8.
plt.figure(figsize = (width, height))

extent = [6, 15, 47, 55]  # Extent of Germany [Long1,2, Lat1,2]

ortho = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=10.5, \
         central_latitude=51.0, \
         globe=None)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ortho)
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.set_extent(extent)

def plot_city_name(lon, lat, cityname):
    """plot city name at specified location"""
    plt.text(lon, lat, cityname, \
             va='center', \
             fontsize=18, \
             ha='right', \
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
             zorder=0)

lat, lon = 52.520007, 13.404954    # Location of Berlin
plot_city_name(lon, lat, 'Berlin')

latd, lond = 51.341734, 7.417392   # Location of Hagen
plot_city_name(lond, latd, 'Hagen')

def plot_hist(mapx, mapy, ax, width):
    """plot simple histogram at specified location"""
    ax_sub= inset_axes(ax, width=width, \
                       height=width, loc=3, \
                       bbox_to_anchor=(mapx, mapy), \
                       bbox_transform=ax.transData, \
                       borderpad=0)
    # plot simple histogram
    ax_sub.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=10, normed=1)

def xy_from_longlat(lon, lat):
    """convert long-lat (degrees) to grid values""" 
    return ortho.transform_point(lon, lat, ccrs.PlateCarree())

# plot histograms at 2 locations
inset_size = 1.0  # unit?

mapx, mapy = xy_from_longlat(lon, lat)
plot_hist(mapx, mapy, ax, inset_size)   # Berlin

mapx, mapy = xy_from_longlat(lond, latd)
plot_hist(mapx, mapy, ax, inset_size)   # Hagen

plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

**Edit**

On ipython/jupyter notebook you can pan and zoom the graphic without breaking the relative locations of the histograms.